# Finding a repetitive pattern in Python strings

Tags: python, regex

Let's suppose I have this string

s = '123123123'

I can notice the '123' sub-string is being repeated.

here = '1234'

The sub-string would be '1234' with no repetitions.

s = '11111'

The sub-string would be '1'

How can I get this with Python? Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

```
strings = ['123123123', '1234', '11111']
import re
pattern, result = re.compile(r'(.+?)\1+'), []
for item in strings:
    result.extend(pattern.findall(item) or [item])
print result
# ['123', '1234', '1']
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ogyYrv9hkYeKtA9q)

You can see the explanation for the RegEx [here](http://regex101.com/r/hN6qN7)

Comment: but he wants 1234 to be detected for the middle string.

Comment: Can't you fix it in the regex?

Comment: @AaronHall That might break if the string is `111112111`?